# Fail to load custom attribute in phtml: Undefined variable: _product

Tags: product-view

I want to display a content of attribute into a new block in product VIEW page. My code is simple:

```
<?php 
echo $_product->getIncommTermos() ;
?>
```

this get me error `Notice: Undefined variable: _product  on line 2`. This file is  a new phtml inside my template/folder/termos.phml and not recognized the variable _product, why? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this

```
<?php
if(Mage::registry('current_prodduct')) 
echo Mage::registry('current_prodduct')->getIncommTermos() ;
?>
```

As $product i`s not define that phtml file`  that `why it show the error`.try with `registry variable`,which give you `the current product model`

Comment: `<?php
if(Mage::registry('current_product')) {
echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getIncommTermos() ;
}
?>`

solved thx

Comment: You are welcome